# sort java iteration output by data

Tags: java, iterator, interactive-brokers

Have the following code, I can not alter expiration. :

```
for (Iterator<String> i = expirations.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
String item = i.next();
System.out.println(+item);
}
```

It prints out the following:

```
20180329
20180615
20180119
20180316
20180921
20180216
20171222
20180105
```

I need to sort that by date and take the first one through something like var result[1];

I tried this but it does not sort:

```
               for (Iterator<String> i = expirations.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    String item = i.next();

     List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(item);

        // Sort list
        Collections.sort(list);
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("sort LIST EXPIRATION: "+iterator.next());
        }
}
```

Comment: So, how are you trying to do it? Could you show us some code for sorting that you have? Also, what is your `expirations`? Probably, provide full code that you have if it is not so big, so it is easier to cp and compile rum it.

Comment: why would you think expirations matters?

Comment: I think, the right approach will be to sort your `expirations` first and only then print it or if you don't want to modify `expirations`, copy it to `TreeSet`, for example. `TreeSet` will sort your data automatically and then you can use https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/treeset_iterator.htm on it.

Comment: I can not alter expirations.

Comment: So, just copy it to the another collection like `TreeSet`, sort this copy and print it.

Comment: can you put that as an answer ?

Comment: i am not sure how to create a tree or sort it

Comment: Thats why I asked to provide minimal compilable code, so I can easily copy and modify it to answer your question.

Comment: above tree see update

Comment: but it still does not update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it for example like this:

```
List<String> expirations = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"20180329", "20180615", "20180119",
    "20180316", "20180921", "20180216", "20171222", "20180105"});

Set<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(expirations);

for (Iterator<String> i = sortedSet.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  String item = i.next();
  System.out.println(item);
}
```

I don't know what is your `expirations`, so I just made it simple list.

The output:

```
20171222
20180105
20180119
20180216
20180316
20180329
20180615
20180921
```

Be aware, though, that `Set` doesn't allow duplicates, so if you want to keep duplicates you have to use another approach.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. It is java basics, I assume, so take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html, for example. In my code `expirations` is a `List`, so you can access its elements by index, like that `expirations.get(0)`, `expirations.get(1)`...

Comment: `item` is a `String` in my code, so what you are trying to access by index in a `String`? if you want just this string added to output, do `System.out.println("TESTING sort= " + item);`

Comment: I am able to print out all of the strings sorted. How can I get just the FIRST item after sort?

Comment: how can I choose just the first result after all are sorted?

Comment: You have to review java basics/collections tutorials. There are many ways how you can do it. For example, you can get it like this `sortedSet.iterator().next()` right after `sortedSet` creation.

Comment: Just add this to the end of my code `Iterator<String> iterator = sortedSet.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext())
      System.out.println("First Element: " + iterator.next());`